# Access Runtime 2010 action query warnings

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, regedit

I have one PC that does not have MS Access installed, therefore I have installed the free runtime version, so that the PC can be used for the database.

I have got the database up and running apart from one issue. When action queries are run they are preceded by a warning message. I have tried changing the trust center settings but I still get the warning.

- Is there a way of stopping this warning message and running the query automatically in the runtime version?

I don't really want to `docmd.setwarnings = false` in VBA, if I'm honest. I think that if my full version works fine, then my runtime version should too.

- Is there something I can do with the registry keys in the `regedit`?

> EDIT

The warning message is as follows:

> "You are about to run an update query that will modify data in your
>   table.Are you sure you want to run this type of action query?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When action queries are run they are preceded by a warning message. I
>   have tried changing the trust center settings but I still get the
>   warning.

Those action query warnings and confirmations have nothing to do with the Trust Center settings.  If you want to suppress them across the board, look at Access Options -> Client Settings and then scroll down to the "Confirm" section.  But I wouldn't recommend you do that.

Use the `DAO.Database.Execute` method as Christopher suggested.  You can use `CurrentDb` for the `DAO.Database`, or set an object variable to `CurrentDb` and use `.Execute` from that variable:

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb
db.Execute "overdue_Query", dbFailOnError
```

The object variable approach allows you to check `db.RecordsAffected` and to get the last-used autonumber value<sup>* see below</sup>: `Debug.Print db.OpenRecordset("SELECT @@Identity")(0)`

Also `.Execute` is flexible in that it will accept either the name of a saved query (as above) or a SQL statement.  So you could do something like this ...

```vb
Dim strDelete As String
strDelete = "DELETE FROM tblFoo;"
db.Execute strDelete, dbFailOnError
MsgBox db.RecordsAffected & " records deleted"
```

---

<sup>*</sup> The autonumber value used by the last `INSERT` executed from that object variable.

Comment: why don't the warnings appear in my full version of access, and only in the runtime version?

Comment: I think those settings are saved somewhere in the registry on the host machine.  So you would have to add them to the registry in the machine which uses the runtime.  But I wouldn't do that, and hope to discourage you from doing it.  ;-)  Use `DAO.Database.Execute` plus `dbFailOnError` instead.

Comment: simply using `currentdb.execute "overdue_query"` worked great, thanks. Im not sure why opening a query doesn't work the same though :/

Comment: `DoCmd.OpenQuery` and `DoCmd.RunSQL` trigger those notices/confirmations.   `DAO.Database.Execute` does not.  I can't say why exactly ... that's just the way MS designed them.  :-)